# Python for-loop breaks my recursive algorithm

Tags: python

I found an edge case for https://1337code.xyz/hard/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/ and wanted to sort it out. For some reason this innocuous for-loop breaks the entire thing except for the edge case. The problematic block in question is commented out

```py
class Node():
    def __init__(self, value, binList):
        self.value = value
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None
        self.binList = binList
        
def binTree(binList, i=0):
    if i < len(binList):
        value = binList[i]
        if value == None:
            return
        node = Node(value, binList)
        node.left_child = binTree(binList, i * 2 + 1)
        node.right_child = binTree(binList, i * 2 + 2)
        return node

def pathFinder(root):
    neg_max = float("-inf")
    # for x in root.binList:
    #     if x != None:
    #         neg_max = max(neg_max, x)
    # if neg_max < 0 and neg_max != float("-inf"):
    #     return neg_max

    try:
        left_sum = max(0, pathFinder(root.left_child))
        right_sum = max(0, pathFinder(root.right_child))
        current_path_sum = root.value + left_sum + right_sum
        return max(current_path_sum, max(left_sum, right_sum))
    except:
        return 0

print("expected 6, output:",pathFinder(binTree([1,2,3])))
print("expected 42, output:",pathFinder(binTree([-10,9,20,None,None,15,7])))
print("expected 35, output:",pathFinder(binTree([-10,-9,20,None,None,15,-7])))
print("expected 20, output:",pathFinder(binTree([-10,-9,-20,None,None,15,-7,None,None,None,None,5])))
print("expected -1, output:",pathFinder(binTree([-1,-2,-3])))
```

When commented out, all tests come out fine except the last one since it will default to 0.
When not commented it breaks.

Commented out:

```bash
expected 6, output: 6
expected 42, output: 42
expected 35, output: 35
expected 20, output: 20
expected -1, output: 0
```

Not commented out:

```bash
expected 6, output: 1
expected 42, output: 20
expected 35, output: 20
expected 20, output: 0
expected -1, output: -1
```

Comment: So what is your **actual question**?  Saying "hey I found this code that doesn't work" is not a question.

Comment: @JohnGordon I assumed it was obvious my question was "why does the for-loop break my code?"

Comment: I haven't worked this all the way through, but note that without the `for` loop, `pathFinder(None)` returns 0. With the `for` loop, `pathFinder(None)` throws an exception for the caller to catch. I suspect this will make the difference. For example, let's say `root` is not None but `root.left_child` is None. Without the loop, `left_sum` is 0 and execution proceeds to calculate `right_sum`. With the loop, `left_sum` throws (with 'NoneType has no attribute binList' or similar), and you go straight to your `except` clause without `right_sum` ever being calculated.

Comment: It looks like the exact opposite of what you're saying.  If you comment out the statement, you get the wrong result.  In any case, the issue is what to return when all the nodes are negative.  If the "empty path" is allowed, then the answer is 0.  If the empty path isn't allowed, then the answer is maximum of the values.  The second half of your code can never return an answer less than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason is that the for loop is not inside a try/except block, and it contains a reference to `root.binList`.

This reference will of course throw an exception if `root` is null -- but that exception *doesn't happen* if the for loop is commented out, and so the function is able to proceed further, thus accounting for the different result.

If you move the for loop to be inside the try/except block, the results are as expected.